# ruby set isn't unique

Tags: ruby, set

For some reason the following code produce a set with duplicate values.
I'm not sure how uniqueness of an array in ruby is defined so maybe this is somehow expectable?

```
require 'set'
xs = [1, 2, 3]
xss = Set.new []
xs.each do |x|
  xss.merge xss.to_a.map{|xs| xs.push x}
  xss.add [x]
  p xss
end
```

will prints

```
#<Set: {[1]}>
#<Set: {[1, 2], [1, 2], [2]}>
#<Set: {[1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3], [3]}>
```

What's wrong?

EDIT
change `xs.push x` to `xs + [x]` will fix it.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 combinations of arbitrary length

Comment: So you want `#<Set: {[[1], [2], [3]], [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]}>`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I want `#<Set: {[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]}>`

Comment: If `arr = [1,2,3]` then this will work `arr.map.with_index(1) {|_,i| arr.combination(i).entries }.flatten(1).to_set`. But hold out, someone may post a better way.

Comment: yup, someone like Stefan:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are effectively altering the objects within the set, which is not allowed.

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

> Set assumes that the identity of each element does not change while it is stored. Modifying an element of a set will render the set to an unreliable state.

---

Regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538881/ruby-set-isnt-unique/44539713?noredirect=1#comment76071160_44538881)

> I want `#<Set: {[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3]}>`

You could use [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

(1..a.size).flat_map { |n| a.combination(n).to_a }
#=> [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: So it's because of push method changing element value, thus break the state? What's the proper way to do it, instead of push?